# Socket bind ipv6 address

Tags: c, sockets

1.I'm trying to bind ipv6 and the problem start from accept() function.When I run this code,it doesn't block at accept() to wait client.It actually print **fe80::70e2:2e35:3028:b080%16 : 12345**
and this address and port is used to bind for server.

2.My ipv6 address starts **fe80**.Does it mean it is a link local address?if so,can I bind it as server address?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <errno.h>


#define WSA_VERSION MAKEWORD(2, 2) // using winsock 2.2

void server2()
{
    char *err = NULL;
    char ip[64] = {0};
    char serv[8] = {0};
    char ch[1024] = {0};
    char hostname[64] = {0};
    char port[] = "12345";

    int status;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *res, *ptr;

    SOCKET s;
    SOCKET client;
    boolean reuse = TRUE;

    struct sockaddr clientaddr; //for programmer
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
    socklen_t len = 64;

    //gethostname
    if (gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname)) < 0)
    {
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                    NULL, WSAGetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPTSTR)&err, 0, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", err);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", hostname);
    }

    //getaddrinfo
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints)); 
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET6;      
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;  
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;      
    if ((status = getaddrinfo(hostname, port, &hints, &res)) != 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", gai_strerror(status));
    }
    else
    {
        for (ptr = res; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next)
        {
            getnameinfo(ptr->ai_addr, len,ip, sizeof(ip),serv, sizeof(serv), NI_NUMERICHOST|NI_NUMERICSERV);
            printf("%s : %s\n",  ip, serv);
        }
    }

    //socket
    if ((s = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol)) < 0)
    {
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                    NULL, WSAGetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPTSTR)&err, 0, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", err);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", "create socket ok");
    }

    //setsockopt
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (const char *)&reuse, sizeof(boolean)) < 0)
    {
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                    NULL, WSAGetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPTSTR)&err, 0, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", err);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", "setsockopt ok");
    }

    //bind
    if (bind(s, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0)
    {
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                    NULL, WSAGetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPTSTR)&err, 0, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", err);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", "bind ok");
        freeaddrinfo(res);           /* No longer needed */
    }

    //listen
    if (listen(s, 5) < 0)
    {
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                    NULL, WSAGetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPTSTR)&err, 0, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", err);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s\n", "listen ok");
    }

    //accept
    if ( (client = accept(s, &clientaddr, &addrlen)) < 0)
    {
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                    NULL, WSAGetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPTSTR)&err, 0, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", err);
    }
    else
    {
        //len = sizeof(clientaddr);
        getnameinfo(&clientaddr, len,ip, sizeof(ip),serv, sizeof(serv), NI_NUMERICHOST|NI_NUMERICSERV);
        printf("%s : %s\n",  ip, serv);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        status = recv(client, ch, sizeof(ch), 0);
        if (status == 0)
        {
            if (closesocket(client) != 0)
            {
                FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                            NULL, WSAGetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPTSTR)&err, 0, NULL);
                printf("%s\n", err);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("close client\n");
            }
            break;
        }
        else if (status == -1)
        {
            FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                        NULL, WSAGetLastError(),MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),(LPTSTR)&err, 0, NULL);
            printf("%d  %s\n",WSAGetLastError(), err);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\n", ch);
        }
    }


}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int iResult;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
    }

    server2();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Link local addresses must be combined with the interface since the address is not unique.  The documentation covers this case.

Comment: Unrelated, but `WSAStartup` should be paired with `WSACleanup`.

Comment: Unrelated, too, but be aware that `recv` is a low level function just transferring data – it does *not* null-terminate any input received, so sender does not include a null character you need to null-terminate yourself before using `printf`. As TCP is stream-based, you additionally have no guarantee that each message sent remotely is received with a single call to `recv` on local side, so you might receive partial messages!

Comment: A simpler solution: `printf("%.*s", status, ch);`...